# Template template argument is not a type

Tags: c++

There is a nested template type that has a template parameter, but this is used in another templated function where the type reference is a dependent name.

```
template <class T1>
struct s
{
    template <class T2>
    struct s2
    {

    };
};

template <template <class> class T>
void func()
{
    T<int>();
}

template <class T>
void func2()
{
    func<s<T>::s2>(); //error
}
```

However, this yields an error:

> error: dependent-name `s<T>::s2` is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
>   note: say `typename s<T>::s2` if a type is meant

Adding `typename` does not help though:

> error: `typename s<int>::s2` names `template<class T2> struct s<int>::s2`, which is not a type

Neither adding `template` works:

> error: parse error in template argument list
>   `func<typename s<T>::template s2>();`

Comment: I read the linked answer, but it didn't talk about template arguments and wasn't helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `typename` disambiguator cannot be used for a template because it indicates a concrete type. It is possible to use the `template` disambiguator but without `typename`, because then it doesn't need the argument list:

```
func<s<T>::template s2>();
```